# setTimeout to animate table images

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I have some code that changes the images in a table.  Works fine until I try to put a timer in to slow it up and make it look like they sort of roll out instead of all just 'snap' into place.  Any help greatly appreciated.  Code below:

```
function showImage(){
    for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++) {
        var showImage = document.getElementById(i);
        showImage.src = i+'.png';
    }
    setTimeout(showImage(),700);
}
```

Comment: and what is the problem with your current code ?

Comment: anyway's .. your showImage function will never exit as soon as you enter it, as you are calling it again and again from within

Comment: Like @DTH said, you need to pass the definition (name) of the function to setTimeout, not execute it. So write `setTimeout(showImage,700);`

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Put the code inside of an immediately invoked function expression:

```
function showImage(){
    for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++){
        (function(i){
            setTimeout(function(){
                var img= document.getElementById('image' + i);
                img.src = i + '.png';
            }, i * 100);
        })(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but the assignment spec asks for using setTimeout to roll out the images.  I have it running fine in another function for a countdown timer but isn't happy with this one (for good reason no doubt).

Comment: I modified the answer. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your function will be called again and again, as you have placed a function call to itself inside the function. Try this (Not tested)

```
function showImages()
{
    for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++) {
        setTimeout(function() {
         showImage(i);
        }, 700)      
    }        
}

function showImage(i)
{
  var showImage = document.getElementById(i);
  showImage.src = i+'.png';    
}
```

If it does not work, try to instrument your code by inserting output to browser console like this inside you loop and in your showImage(i) function:

```
console.log("insert what you want to output here");
```

In chrome (and other browsers) hit F12 to bring up the debugger and make sure you have the console tab selected. Now you should be able to debug your scripts using logging.

Comment: Thanks but I still can't get either of these to work.  I'm calling the function from a button onClick also.

Comment: @shep try outputting your showImage variable to see that the result is ok. Also instrument your code here and there to be sure that you get into your function etc.

Comment: @shep: try it with my updated code ... I had made a stupid mistake :)

Comment: Thanks for your help, I tried you updated code but still no cigar.  I do see what you're saying though.  I might try and attack it another way.  Or just drop it and take a hit on the marking.

Comment: @shep: added some more to the answer to help you debug using the console of the browser. This will help you identify if your functions are even called and/or if the problem is something entirely different..